# Argument of type 'Event' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CdkDragMove<any>'

Tags: javascript, angular-material, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to get the position of a draggable element as it's moved around, but I can't find any attribute that works with CdkDragMove.

**HTML Template**

```
<div
  cdkDropList
  [cdkDropListData]="day.lunch"
  [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="dropTargetIds"
  class="example-list"
  (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
  (cdkDragMoved)="dragMoved($event)" // <--- Error (see below)
  >
    //Actual content
  </div>
```

**TypeScript**

```
dragMoved(event:CdkDragMove<any>){
    // get PosX & PosY
  }
  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<Recipe[]>) {
    // other stuff
  }
```

I get this error:

> Argument of type 'Event' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'CdkDragMove'.   Type 'Event' is missing the following properties
> from type 'CdkDragMove': source, pointerPosition, event,
> distance, deltangtsc

I also tried with dragMoved instead of $event but then I get this

> Argument of type '(event: CdkDragMove) => void' is not assignable
> to parameter of type 'CdkDragMove'.   Type '(event:
> CdkDragMove) => void' is missing the following properties from
> type 'CdkDragMove': source, pointerPosition, event, distance,
> delta

I can't get my head around this, 'cause the event is working on the drop function instead.
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved**

I found out that the `(cdkDragMoved)="dragMoved($event)"` binding had to be placed at the `cdkDrag` element, and not at the `cdkDropList` element.

```
<div
            cdkDropList
            [cdkDropListData]="day.lunch"
            [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="dropTargetIds"
            class="example-list"
            (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
            // It was here
          >
            <mat-chip-list class="mat-chip-list-stacked" >
              <mat-chip cdkDrag (cdkDragMoved)="dragMoved($event)"> //<--- Must be Here
                // content
              </mat-chip>
            </mat-chip-list>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 11):

I got this error when I had failed to import the `DragDropModule` into my module.

```
import { DragDropModule } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
```

Comment: In the last Angular 16, if it's standalone, we can just import `CdkDropList, CdkDrag`

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says you need to add a Type to tell the cdkDragMoved what is being moved. Like you already did for drop:

```js
dragMoved(event:CdkDragMove<Recipe[]>){
   // get PosX & PosY
}
```

See the Documentation: https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api

Comment: I've already tried with type "Recipe", type "Recipe[ ]" and also with type "any".
Same error everytime. I just forgot to type it in the post.